# how to add props in route component in react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

As heading states, I used to have a page with a stateful component that gets different props based on changes to url made from .

Now, upgraded to react router v6, I really do not understand how to make it work again. I do understand that the only way to solve this now is using hooks such as useNavigate, but I do not know how this can be implemented in my code. I have read through react-router v6 documentation and still do not understand how to solve my issue.

Se below codes. Codes are ordered from child component and up to index.tsx.  component is extensive and is basically a statfulcomponent that gets its states from props. And based on the props given it will display its content accordingly.

Please could someone suggest a solution for my set-up?

**CalculatorPage.tsx**

```
import Calculator from "../components/Calculator";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { FlowrateCalc } from "../calc/calculators/FlowrateCalc";
import { ValveKvsCalc } from "../calc/calculators/ValveKvsCalc";
import { AccelerationCalc } from "../calc/calculators/AccelerationCalc";

export default function CalculatorPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      {/* when changing links, there is no props being sent to Calculator. Calculator is a STATEFUL component*/}
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path={"flow"}
          element={<Calculator {...FlowrateCalc} />}
        />
        <Route
          path={"kvs"}
          element={<Calculator {...ValveKvsCalc} />}
        />
        <Route
          path={"acceleration"}
          element={<Calculator {...AccelerationCalc} />}
        />
      </Routes>
      
      <Link to={"flow"}>
        <button style={{ color: "green" }}>flow</button>
      </Link>
      <Link to={"kvs"}>
        <button style={{ color: "red" }}>kvs</button>
      </Link>
      <Link to={"acceleration"}>
        <button style={{ color: "blue" }}>acceleration</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Main.tsx**

```
import { Route , Routes} from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "../pages/HomePage";
import CalculatorPage from "../pages/CalculatorPage";
import AboutPage from "../pages/AboutPage";


export default function Main() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>} />
        <Route path="/calculator/*" element={<CalculatorPage/>} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage/>} />
      </Routes>

    </div>
  );
}
```

**App.tsx**

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import Header from "./layout/Header";
import Footer from "./layout/Footer";
import Main from "./layout/Main";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Main />
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Index.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from './state';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Have you include all relevant code in your question? What props are you specifically referring to that need to be passed to the routed components? Are you referring to the old RRDv5 [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props)? Where are you using a `navigate` (*from `useNavigate` hook*)? This question needs more context. Can you share this `Calculator` component, both how it was used in the RRDv5 days, and currently now in v6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely can pass props to the components of a Routes Router...

Check it:

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/page' element={<Page props={'helloWorld from Props'}/>}/>
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

And then in Page.js:

```
function Page(props){

console.log(props)

return(
    <div>
    </div>
```

It seems to work just like it did before. *shrug*

Comment: No it doesn't work

Comment: @FlavienLaureau How does this not work? The `props` prop is passed to the `Page` component.

Answer (score 5):

Unless anyone has another answer, there seem to be no such solution. As of react router v6 there is no passing of props via router. Instead we have to use functional components and react router hooks to detect url changes.

Comment: See other answers related to `useParams`. Please remove the selection of this answer as "the" answer, even though it has the most upvotes.

Comment: This answer couldn't be more incorrect. Passing props works exactly the same like it does anywhere else in React, e.g.  `element={<Calculator {...FlowrateCalc} />}` like you have in the code in your post, i.e. the `FlowrateCalc` props are passed to `Calculator`.

Comment: Hi Drew. You are correct. I do not remember why I had such difficulty making it work back then. In my new projects the I can pass props just fine. I will change the correct answer. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

You can use hooks provided by react-router-dom to pull params data from the URL.

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

const params = useParams(); // inside your component
```

This allows you to pull data from the URL

[This official docs link might help you as well](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useparams)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a store, and if needed, `useSelector` hook help you usefully for that time.

With using `useSelector`, you easily will get the store's state.

Use:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const CounterComponent = () => {
  const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter)
  return <div>{counter}</div>
}
```

Comment: Yes, I went ahead and used redux for my project. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in v6 of react router dom we can not use props like path. Instead if you want to use params you can use hooks:

```
import useParams 

const { id } = useParams();
```

Comment: how do you tests this with your component and set the browser url?