# react-router-dom v6: Route's render prop equivalent in v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

in my routes.js with react router v6 this block of code would work but now it's unable to render the component. Instead i get this error

Matched leaf route at location does not have an element. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

```
<Route
          path="/callback"
          render={(props) => {
            context.handleAuth(props);
            return <Callback />;
          }}
        />
```

I'm trying to figure out how to pass the props into my callback component in v6

Comment: Is this actually what you're looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69962512/how-to-add-props-in-route-component-in-react-router-dom-v6

If you want to handle Auth, you'll maybe need this : https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/auth?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: There is no RRDv6 equivalent, per se. What "props" does this `context.handleAuth` function expect/need? What is the overall goal the old v5 code was achieving that you now need the v6 code to do?

Answer (score 0):

Version 6 favours element over components to.  In version 6, you may do it this way:

Use the follwing in `<Callback />`

```
const params = useParams();
```

```
useEffect(() => {
   /* If context is avialable here. */
   context.handleAuth(params);
}, [])
```

For more info, read the doc here:

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#advantages-of-route-element

See more:

https://medium.com/frontendweb/how-to-pass-state-or-data-in-react-router-v6-c366db9ee2f4

Comment: I tried this but the params aren't getting set. Can post more snippets of my code to provide more clarification? @mahan